# how to draw a line in html 30pt from either side

Tags: html, css

I have a footer div that is 100% wide and 200pt high.  I want to draw a white line that starts 30pt in from both the left and the right 25pt from the bottom.

I have playing about with a div 1px high and positioning it with the following but to now avail.

```
    #HPFooterlinebreak{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25pt;
    right:30pt;
    left:30pt;
    background-color:#EFF1EF;
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Just to be clear the div above is not the one 200pt high.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a positioned [**pseudo element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) with a suitably applied border?

> pseudo-elements are added to selectors but instead of describing a
>   special state, they allow you to style certain parts of a document

You may also want to use the semantic [**footer element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) (if appropriate)

```css
footer {
  background: black;
  height: 200pt;
  position: relative;
}
footer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 30pt;
  right: 30pt;
  bottom: 25pt;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You don't need the `width`. Also, if you use `position: absolute` to position the element inside its parent, then you must also add `position: relative` or `position: absolute` to the parent itself.

By the way, if this white line is just for show, you might as well use a pseudo-element for it and keep the HTML simple. But if you like to, you might as well change `.footer:before` back to `#HPFooterlinebreak`.

```css
.footer {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
.footer:before{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25pt;
    right:30pt;
    left:30pt;
    background-color:#EFF1EF;
    height:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Yo
</div>
```